# Select Subset from SQL Table with query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset where users have services (PC, Laptop) against there login id's. i need to select only those login id's which have both the services regardless of the service class.

i tried to use row_number() with partition on loginID but its not working.
here i only want to select 10014 and 10016 and there are more also.

I tried the follwing:

```
select * from ( select *, ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition by LoginID Order by LoginID) RowNumber from data a) as x where x.RowNumber > 1
```

But it gives me only the second row.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `cte` with `count(distinct serviceCode) = 2` (users with both services) to find proper `LoginID` and then `join` it to the main table.

```
with cte as (
select
    LoginID
from data 
group by LoginID
having count(distinct ServiceCode) = 2
)
select
    *
from data d
join cte c
    on d.LoginID = c.LoginID
```

Answer (score 0):

If `'PC'` and `'Laptop'` are the only possible values then you only need to count the distinct values of `ServiceCode` for every `LoginID`:

```
SELECT LoginID
FROM data 
GROUP BY LoginID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ServiceCode) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the login ids, use aggregation:

```
select loginid
from data
where servicecode in (10, 11)
having count(distinct servicecode) = 2;
```

If you want the original rows, one method is `exists`:

```
select d.*
from data d
where d.servicecode in (10, 11) and
      exists (select 1
              from data d2
              where d2.servicecode in (10, 11) and
                    d2.loginid = d.loginid
             );
```

That is, get all rows with a 10/11 service code for a login when the other value exists.